GroupPrincipal.GetMembers(true) recursive - Was a person in original group or a nested group
using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADDomain))
            {
                using (var gp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, identity))
                {
                    if (gp != null)
                    {
                        var members = gp.GetMembers(true);

                        foreach (var item in members)
                        {
                             /*
                             * Handle the member but i need info if the memeber comes from the                    original group or a nested one and if its from a nested one, what was the name of the group?
                             */
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

I need to get members from a group (recursive) but i need to keep track of if the member is from the original group or from a nested one, and preferably what the name of the nested group then was.
Looking around i did not find much about this at all.
